# How can I define a different target folder for some dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2, build

I run many instances of the same web application under Tomcat and to save memory I copy some of the libraries to Tomcat's lib (tomcat\lib) and shared (tomcat\shared) folders. Libraries that go under lib can be found by both Tomcat and web applications, libraries that go under the shared-folder can only be used by web applications. My web application also need some libraries on the web application level so those libraries goes under WEB-INF\lib.

I have defined in my pom.xml that most libraries have a scope of provided so that they're not copied to WEB-INF\lib, however is there any way to define that I would like some libraries to go under a custom-defined folder; e.g. WEB-INF\lib\tomcat\shared and WEB-INF\lib\tomcat\lib, from where I could mover them manually to Tomcat's corresponding folders on the server?

Answer (score 1):

That is not really the recommended way to package dependencies, as usually the web application would be deployed without furhter modification of the war file.

I think you can archieve what you want using the [dependency:copy-dependencies goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html), but it would require some configuration. You would have to set `includeScope` to `provided`, set the correct `outputDirectory` and then define the artifacts with the `includeGroupIds` or `includeArtifactIds` options.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Yes, I understand this is a special case but when I have around 100 web applications that uses the same libraries there is some serious memory to be saved by sharing the libraries.

But I'll check out the copy-dependencies goal, I took a quick look at it before I wrote the question here on stackoverflow but it looked quite complicated, just wondering if there was a more easy way to achieve this.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with sharing the libraries, what I wanted to discourage was to also package these inside the war file. Maybe an alternative would be to create separate projects for bundling the dependencies using the assembly plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate maven project which contains the war file and define the dependencies which should be located in the share-folder as scope: provided. Furthermore create an other separate module which has these dependencies and create an appropriate archive from it via maven-assembly-plugin...